# What is this annoying Visual Studio autocomplete feature?

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete

Since about an hour ago I have the MOST annoying feature on Visual Studio 2022 community edition.

Whenever I type in the editor and hit `spacebar` it randomly includes one of those suggested lines in my page.

I can get around it by typing very slowly, but if I type quickly it autocompletes.

[image]

Can anyone help me identify what this is and how to turn it off. This is a serious issue as I am supposed to add hints all over the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to toggle IntelliSense autocomplete to see if that solves your problem:

`Edit` -> `IntelliSense` -> `Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion`

[image: Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion]

Comment: Thx, that worked, it drove me insane.

I see there is also a shorcut `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Space`